Why doesn't my state become false when I click the close button on my menu?
Even though I initialize my state to false, when I open my menu and close it it never becomes false, therefore the closing animation of the NavBar never runs and I don't know why.
The component:
import CloseButton from "./CloseButton"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const NavBar = ({ state, setStateFunction }: { state: boolean, setStateFunction: (value: boolean) => void }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(state);
    }, [state]);
    return (
        <div className={`w-[370px] bg-black fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen transform transition-transform duration-1000 ${state === false ? 'animate-translateX0' : 'animate-translateX'}`}>
            <button className="absolute top-5 right-5 font-bold text-2xl" onClick={() => {setStateFunction(false)}}><CloseButton /></button>
            <div className="ml-6 mt-20">
                <nav className="">
                    <ul className="">
                        <li className="mb-5 hover:translate-x-3 tracking-wider"><a className="hover:text-gray-200 hover:translate-x-3 transition transform" href="">HOME</a></li>
                        <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider"><a href="">CLOTHES</a></li>
                        <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider"><a href="">ELECTRONICS</a></li>
                        <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider"><a href="">FURNITURE</a></li>
                        <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider"><a href="">SHOES</a></li>
                        <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider"><a href="">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
                        <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider"><a href="">OFFERS</a></li>
                        <li className="tracking-wider"><a href="">SALE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <span className="ms-madi-regular tracking-wider text-2xl -rotate-12 absolute bottom-24 left-32">WebWish</span>
        </div>
    )
}
export function Header() {
    const [asideBar, setAsideBar] = useState(false)


    return (
        <header
            className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 w-screen h-20 p-7 z-20 bg-black overflow-hidden"
        >
            <nav className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center text-customGray pr-4">
                <div>
                    <button onClick={() => 
                                setAsideBar(true)
                       } className="mr-4">
                        {/* <MenuIcon /> */}
                    </button>
                    {asideBar === true && <NavBar state={asideBar} setStateFunction={setAsideBar} />}
                    <button>
                        {/* <SearchIcon /> */}
                    </button>
                </div>
                <span className="ms-madi-regular tracking-wider text-2xl -rotate-12">WebWish</span>
                <div>
                    <button className="mr-3">
                        <a href="/auth/login">
                            {/* <LoginIcon /> */}
                        </a>
                    </button>
                    <button>
                        {/* <ShopIcon /> */}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

My index.tsx:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { NavBar } from "./components/NavBar";
import { useState } from "react";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {
  const [asideBar, setAsideBar] = useState(false);

  return (
    <main
      className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 ${inter.className}`}
    >
      <button onClick={() => setAsideBar(true)} className="mr-4">
        Open the sidebar
      </button>

      <button onClick={() => setAsideBar(false)} className="mr-4">
        close sidebar
      </button>

      {asideBar && <NavBar state={asideBar} setStateFunction={setAsideBar} />}
    </main>
  );
}

I tried to change the state in several ways, I tried toggle, in fact the state did not change directly,I don't know if the condition I have in the component is wrong or if it is something else

You haven't given any indication for what CSS animate-translateX0 or animate-translateX would apply.
You could look at using a CSS transition, transitioning between -translate-x-full or translate-x-0 (implicit default) to slide the sidebar in and out. For CSS transitions to "play", the element must be in the DOM before the change of the transition happens. So, to simplify this, we could remove the conditional render and always have the elements in the DOM, toggling the -translate-x-full class only.


const CloseButton = () => "CloseButton";
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const NavBar = ({ state, setStateFunction }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className={`w-[370px] bg-black fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen transition-transform duration-1000 ${state === false ? "-translate-x-full" : ""}`}>
      <button
        className="absolute top-5 right-5 font-bold text-2xl"
        onClick={() => {
          setStateFunction(false);
        }}
      >
        <CloseButton />
      </button>
      <div className="ml-6 mt-20">
        <nav className="">
          <ul className="">
            <li className="mb-5 hover:translate-x-3 tracking-wider">
              <a className="hover:text-gray-200 hover:translate-x-3 transition transform" href="">
                HOME
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider">
              <a href="">CLOTHES</a>
            </li>
            <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider">
              <a href="">ELECTRONICS</a>
            </li>
            <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider">
              <a href="">FURNITURE</a>
            </li>
            <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider">
              <a href="">SHOES</a>
            </li>
            <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider">
              <a href="">MISCELLANEOUS</a>
            </li>
            <li className="mb-5 tracking-wider">
              <a href="">OFFERS</a>
            </li>
            <li className="tracking-wider">
              <a href="">SALE</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <span className="ms-madi-regular tracking-wider text-2xl -rotate-12 absolute bottom-24 left-32">WebWish</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const inter = { className: "" };

function Home() {
  const [asideBar, setAsideBar] = useState(false);

  return (
    <main className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 ${inter.className}`}>
      <button onClick={() => setAsideBar(true)} className="mr-4">
        Open the sidebar
      </button>

      <button onClick={() => setAsideBar(false)} className="mr-4">
        close sidebar
      </button>

      <NavBar state={asideBar} setStateFunction={setAsideBar} />
    </main>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<Home />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



